# aggregate function on the from clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g

A query which should give output which has years as the column name and number of employee who hired in that year. Hire date will be their in column `hire_date`.
I wrote a code  its like

`SELECT count(e.employee_id) total, count(a.employee_id) _2002, count(b.employee_id) _2003, count(c.employee_id) _2004, count(d.employee_id) _2005`

`FROM hr.employees e, 
(select employee_id from hr.employees where extract(year from hire_date)=2002) a,
(select employee_id from hr.employees where extract(year from hire_date)=2003) b,
(select employee_id from hr.employees where extract(year from hire_date)=2004) c,
(select employee_id from hr.employees where extract(year from hire_date)=2005) d;`.
Its showing '0' in every column. Where i went wrong?

Note: data are present for all the conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - From observing your code, you are using multiple tables in the **FROM clause** with comma as a delimiter which is an **IMPLICIT CROSS JOIN** which returns the Cartesian product of rows from tables in the join. Its result would be the rows from Table A multiplied by rows from Table B with a 1:1 match. If you have 10 rows for each table and has a 1:1 match then the result would be 100 rows(in short, it returns the all the rows `from both tables` that are matched).In your case, your table listings doesnt have matched rows due to the WHERE clause/condition that makes their row unique so the result would obviously equal to 0.
> - Alternatively, you just use **CASE STATEMENT** and aggregate function **SUM** to get your expected result without using multiple table or join.Like this:

```
SELECT count(employee_id) total, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date)=2002 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) col_1999,
            SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date)=2003 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) col_1998, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date)=2004 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) col_1997, 
            SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(YEAR FROM hire_date)=2005 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) col_1996 
            FROM hr.employees ;
```

> Note that using commas to delimit multiple tables(IMPLICT JOIN) in a query is still working on ORACLE but it is preferred to use EXPLICIT JOIN. [Read this to know why it is better to use EXPLICIT than IMPLICIT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44917/explicit-vs-implicit-sql-joins/317465#317465)

Answer (score 1):

I got the result using a slit different method 

`SELECT count(employee_id) total, t1.a _2002, t2.b _2003, t3.c _2004, t4.d _2005`

`FROM hr.employees,
(select count(employee_id) as a from hr.employees where extract(year from hire_date)=2002) t1,
(select count(employee_id) as b from hr.employees where extract(year from hire_date)=2003) t2,
(select count(employee_id) as c from hr.employees where extract(year from hire_date)=2004)t3,
(select count(employee_id) as d from hr.employees where extract(year from hire_date)=2005) t4
group by t1.a , t2.b ,t3.c ,t4.d;`
 
It gives the same answer. but I want to know why the the query in the question
don't work. Please do give me the reason.
Thank you.